# R data.frame order

Tags: r

I want to order data.frame by different columns

```
    xx = mtcars
    oi1 = order(xx$mpg,xx$cyl)
    oi2 = order(xx$cyl,xx$disp,xx$hp)
```

etc,

Is there a way I can pass a list of columns to order?

something like:

```
   my.order = c('disp','wt','carb')
   oi = order(xx,my.order)
```

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you could use `do.call` to make parameters from a list. For example

```
my.order = c('disp','wt','carb')
do.call("order", mtcars[my.order])
```

Comment: nice! I see that it is doing exactly what I need. but how?

Comment: Like I said, `do.call` turns lists into parameters to a function. And here we use the fact that `data.frames` are just lists. You can read the `do.call` help page for more info.